# Power consumption in houses by date

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm starting with Power Bi and I need some help to create the data model for this practice case.

I receive the data in a table that has the power consumption of different houses by hour. In the first column it has the date and hour and the rest of columns has the power consumption of each house (one column for each house).

My idea is to create a dashboard with a map as a filter to select the house and a date slicer to filter a period of time.

I dont know exactly what is the better way to face that, if create a subtable for each house or what.

I know that I also have to create another table with the information of each house with coordinates and relate it to the information table, but this information table has the name of the houses in the header of each column and the name is followed by the text "Power Cosumption".

I would appreciate your help, I think that this is not a complicate problem and you can give me some clues or examples to face it.

Thanks!
Regards

Comment: Please share your sample data in text format!

Comment: First transform the source data to have columns (HouseNumber, Date, Lat, Lon, consumption).  IE Unpivot the houses. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/unpivot-column